# jquery conflict in Ruby on rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinyscrollbar

I am working on one application in which I am getting conflicted render result due to 2 jquery file, this is the code in which I am getting error

```
   <!-- tab scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>



<!-- Scrollbar -->  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
                $('.scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar();
                $('.scrollbar3').tinyscrollbar();
            });
                });

            </script>
```

now as you can see there are 2 .js file call , if I write `tools.min.js` prior to the `tinyscrollbar.min.js` it wont load , and same applicable for vice versa

I have tried to merge both of the query but didnt succeed , I dont know how to use `noconflict function()`  can any one help me ??

Comment: Do you have a link to the `timeentry.js` plugin you are using. Also you are wrapping a `$(document).ready`(shorthand) inside a `$(document).ready`(non-shorthand)

Comment: First, remove the inner `$(function () {});`; it's redundant. It does the same as `$(document).ready(function () {});`.

Comment: @m90 sorry error is in tinyscrollbar.min.js :http://code.google.com/p/ajaxart/source/browse/trunk/lib/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js?spec=svn7031&r=7031

Comment: @paul yape did it :) , but didnt solved it ..

Comment: The code above still has a syntax error. Remove the last `});`.

Comment: @paul :D  , Is it possible that I can call specific jquery on specific page load event??like to put them in some condition block ?? 
In this case what I have did is I have declared all this jqery in application.html.erb file which is in layout folder.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have declared this both js file in my app/views/layout/application.html.erb but due to conflict I declared tinyscrollbar.min.js to its local view file:app/view/profile/new.html.erb and it solved my error :)

Comment: another option u can try that, put your javascript in /assets/javascript/scroller/tinyscrollbar.min.js  and add this js only from the page where required and change application.js settings to //= require_directory . , so when application loads it only loads js files in javascript folder not from inner folders